# Is this a variation on the epsilon-delta definition on limits?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ exists. Prove there exists a constant $M$ and a $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

From the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limits, we know that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. At first, I thought about making $M$ analogous to the $\epsilon$, but then realized that $M$ is a fixed value whereas $\epsilon$ describes an interval around a certain point. Essentially, we want the values $f(x)$ to be between $(-M,M)$ for $x$ in the interval $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$. At least, I think this is the way I should be headed, but am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think your statement is truncated, presumably you have "if $|x-a| < \delta$ then ..."

Comment: Sorry, what is $M$ supposed to be? A constant such that...?

Comment: Yeah, what is your M. I think you need to finish your first paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I hope this makes sense now.

Comment: I've done this problem before, but many years ago. I'm probably not doing it right, so I have a partial answer as a comment here.

Comment: Given $\epsilon > 0$, if $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x) = L$, then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x- a| < \delta$ implies that 
$$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow -\epsilon < f(x)-L<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow L-\epsilon < f(x) < L+\epsilon\text{.}$$ Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, fix $\epsilon_0 > 0$. Then $L - \epsilon_0 < f(x) < L + \epsilon_0\text{.}$ Let $M = L + \epsilon_0$. Then clearly $f(x) < M$. Now for $L > 0$, $-M = -L-\epsilon_0 < L - \epsilon_0 < f(x)\text{.}$ I can't figure out the $L \leq 0$ case.

Comment: I assume I've chosen the wrong $M$. If I find the correct $M$, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Bartle and Sherbert's *Introduction to Real Analysis*, 3rd ed..

> **4.2.2 Theorem** If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ has a limit at $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is bounded on
>   some neighborhood of $c$.

**Proof**. Since the limit exists, there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x - c| < \delta$, then 
$$|f(x)|-|L|\leq |f(x)-L| < 1\text{.}$$
Let $V_{\delta}(c)$ be the $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$. [$V_{\delta}(c) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: |x - c|< \delta\}$.] If $x \in A \cap V_{\delta}(c)$, $x \neq c$, then manipulating the previous inequality gives
$$|f(x)| < 1 + |L|\text{.}$$
If $c \notin A$, let $M = |L| + 1$; otherwise, let $M = \sup\{|L|+1, |f(c)|\}$. [Think! - why do we have to define $M$ differently in both cases?]

In both cases, if $x \in A \cap V_{\delta}(c)$, $|f(x)| \leq M$. $\square$

Comment: [] is my own commentary.